# Remove surrounding quotes/parenthesis/brackets/etc on IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way on IntelliJ to remove surrounding parenthesis, brackets, quotes, etc? For example, if I have:

```
"string"
```

Is there any way to remove the matching quotes and get this?

```
string
```

Answer (score 11):

Not directly, but the following replace expression (ctrl+R, tick `Regex`) might help:

Search for: `"(.*)"`

replace with: `$1`

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment why this answer isn't correct?

Comment: For one thing, it wouldn't work for nestable stuff such as parenthesis, as it wouldn't track the correct matching element. I didn't downvote this, though, so I don't know if that was the reason. For me, though, I want something to type after ^W to the correct scope.

Comment: Probably `"(.*?)"` for non-greedy matching

Answer (score 7):

Edit: I found an easier way (plugin code with regex left below for nostalgia)

Webstorm has extend selection and shrink selection
on mac they are bound to alt-upArrow and alt-downArrow

You can use extend selection to select the content and the quotes/braces/parens, then record a macro (i called mine unwrap) and perform the following actions:

1. shrink selection once
2. copy
3. extend selection once
4. paste

then you can save the macro and add a key binding.

Any time you want to unwrap something, you can just extend the selection until it includes the outer braces, then hit your hotkey and it will replace the selection including the braces with their inner contents.

---

I made a [mini-plugin](https://github.com/onezoomin/intellij-live-plugins/tree/master/unwrap),

which i install/code using [live-plugin](https://github.com/dkandalov/live-plugin).

It relies on this Regex:

```
[\["'({](.+)['"})\]]
```

The Regex will also often work in the Search/Replace function in webstorm 
(with Regex and In Selection checked), but it fails in mysterious cases:

- eg. single quotes that are inside parens - even if the outer parens are not in the selection to be considered

Comment: The macro solution would not work for cases when you have to extend selection multiple times. For example, "string string" - when multiple words are in a string.

Answer (score 5):

IDEA have an action to go to matching brace.
You can create macro with something like: goto next brace - delete one char - goto prev brace - delete one more char.
And then set kb shortcut to this macro.

Comment: Currently, the macro execution for this is broken in Linux. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-338835/Macros-execution-stops-when-dialog-window-closes.-Linux-only-bug.

Answer (score 2):

1. Hold `option` on mac, and press `up` key until the inner content is selected
2. Cut (`command+x`) the selected part except the surrounding parenthesis, brackets, quotes, etc.
3. do step 1 to select the surrounding thing, and remove them.
4. Past (`command+v`) the content.

That's how I do it.

There is an [unwrap/remove](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-source-code.html?_gl=1*1l9dnn*_ga*Njc2MzE4NDA0LjE2OTAxMzUyMDE.*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTY5MDEzNTIwMC4xLjEuMTY5MDEzNjk3My4wLjAuMA..&_ga=2.123673035.1190451432.1690135203-676318404.1690135201#unwrap_remove_statement) functionality in the code menu, but don't do what expected in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

[Cursive](https://cursive-ide.com/) for Clojure has the shortcut: Splice Sexp, which is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> on Mac.

Comment: My fault this is part of the Cursive plugin apparently

Comment: Well, that's useful. It's not available on Clion, but I'll check it out next time I use IntelliJ.

Comment: @drew, you should update your answer by mentioning the cursive plugin.
I have cursive installed and the answer helped me. I'll upvote once you update the answer.